# Use cell text to reference sheet name in formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating a summary page for daily production reports. All sheets are in one workbook. Daily sheets are named 17-Oct, 16-Oct, 15-Oct, etc with a Monthly Summary sheet. The summary sheet contains a table with the first column being dates in the same date format as the tabs. I want to use the date in the first column of the summary worksheet to reference the tab with the same name and pull data from it. I have been trying to figure out a way to use the Indirect function to do this but nothing I've tried works. I don't want to have to manually edit the formula in each row to reference the corresponding sheet. I've seen similar questions but the solutions are not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are numbers in Excel shown as the format dictates and sheet names are strings.

You will need to format the number as text in the INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(A1,"dd-mmm") & "'!A1")
```